# Spock: Select visible elements

Tags: groovy, selector, visibility, spock, geb

I have the html in my Page:

[image]

I have the content defined as:

```
child_criteria(wait: true) { $("div",class:"childSelectInIndex").find("ul",class:"oldSelectIndex") }
```

trying to select only the number of visible element those do not have `style="dsplay:none"`
with :

```
def displayedchild_count =  child_criteria.find("li",class:"targetChildAgeForm").not("li",class:"targetChildAgeForm",style:"display:none;").size()
```

But `println displayedchild_count`  always show the size as 4.

How I can select the size of visible elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
def visibleLis = $("div.childSelectInIndex ul.oldSelectIndex li.targetChildAgeForm")
                      .findAll { it.displayed }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. 
Can you please let me know what was the problem in my code?

Comment: Not sure, I've never done visibility checking that way :-(